# Windows Specific Route not followed to 192.168.0.0/24 subnet

Tags: windows, networking, router, routing, subnet

My IP address is 10.0.1.15 and I am trying to route to access an IP address on 192.168.0.0/24 through a deafault gateway of 10.0.2.133. Can someone please explain why tracert to 192.168.0.134 is still goes to 10.0.1.254 and not 10.0.2.133?

```
C:\Users\administrator>route print
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.0.1.254        10.0.1.15      6
         10.0.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link         10.0.1.15    261
        10.0.1.15  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.1.15    261
       10.0.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.1.15    261
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0       10.0.2.133        10.0.1.15      7
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         10.0.1.15    261
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.1.15    261
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.0.1.254       1
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0       10.0.2.133       1
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

C:\Users\administrator>tracert 192.168.0.134

Tracing route to 192.168.0.134 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.0.1.254
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3  ^C
```

Comment: AFAIK, you can't use a gateway that isn't on the same subnet as you. The address of the other router you've listed isn't on the same subnet as you and is therefore unreachable.

Comment: Update: You CAN use a gateway for a static route that is on another subnet as long as your default gateway has a route to the other gateway.

Comment: @SamForbis In this example, we need a static route on the firewall 10.0.1.254 to route 192.168.0.0/24 to 10.0.2.233?

Comment: The short version is your PC (on the 10.0.1.0/24 subnet, I presume) does not have a route to 10.0.2.233, unless you create a route to that address/subnet on your PC or your main router. And there are a number of reasons why that could/could not work for what you're trying to do - it all depends on the configuration of your routers and your network. I'm afraid I can't give you a simple "do this" kind of answer without more information.